# Visual Studio 2013 Entity Framework Generate from database missing

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect to a datebase on my local SQLEXPRESS server. The problem is that when I try to make a model with Ado.Net item I don't have the option "Generate from database". I have these options:

- EF Designer from database
- Empty EF designer model
- Empty code first model
- Code first from database

Do you know how I can choose a "Generate from database" option?

Answer (score 2):

This is new wizard of the ADO.NET Entity Data Model. When you update the Visual Studio this wizard also updated. Yes you can choose the model from the Database with the help of the first option named EF Designer from database.

You can refer to the following article in which I've defined to select the table from the ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-asynchronous-programming-with-entity-framework/

Just got the idea from there. If you still have problem then tell me.

Answer (score 1):

"EF Designer from database" for *.edmx models or "Code first from database" for code-first models should be what you are searching. If not please explain what you excpect to get from the "Generate from database".